# Hadoop - Sharing data between reducers through sockets

Tags: java, api, sockets, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a Java MapReduce program and I was wondering if I could share data between reducers using sockets or any other way. If it will be through sockets, how to retrieve the ip address and port number of the machine operating the reducer for a certain key?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate via your own custom sockets, and to locate the particular host that's running the reducer for a particular key, you can use the JobClient API to query the job tracker for a running jobs reducer list.

To find the reducer host, run the key through your jobs Partitioner (Hash in most cases), determine the reducer task number (0 to num reducers-1) and then find the machine that reducer task is running on (acquired from the JOb Tracker via the JobClient API).

Some things for consideration though:

- What happens if all your reducers can't all run in parallel (more reducers than reducer slots, or another job running concurrently)?
- If the job tracker schedules two or more reducers to run on the same task node, how will you assign port numbers to ensure they both are not trying to listen on the same number (i guess you should pick a base port number, say 21000, and then each reducer will listen to a port whose number is that plus the reducer number). What happens if that port is already in use by another process?

Comment: -> you mean to say, use JobClient API from the reducers right?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have a question, I am familiar with the Partitioner, as mine is a custom one, however I don't know how to get the machine the reducer is running on via the job tracker!
So please any help with it will be so appreciated.

Comment: @WaleedLutfi - you know i've just looked through the JobClient API for 1.2.1 and there doesn't appear to be a nice programmatic way to obtain the task tracker name for a Task Attempt ID. I guess you'll need to scrap the task status page (http://localhost:50030/taskdetails.jsp?tipid=task_201309291015_0001_r_000000) and find the machine column.